# getline() output null when passed a pointer from outer function in c

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to read line from a file, when i use getline directly in the batch_mode function it works fine but when i refactor the code in a separate function it gives me a error.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 2)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  batch_mode(argv[1]);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

batch_mode function

```
void batch_mode(char *path) {
  char *line = NULL;
  ssize_t error = 0;
  char *cmd = NULL;
  FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Coudn't read file\n");
    return;
  }

  while (error != -1) {
    read_line(line, file, cmd);
    error = -1;

    int thread = fork();

    if (thread == 0) {
      char *myargs[] = {NULL};

      execv(cmd, myargs);
    } else {
      thread = wait(NULL);
    }
  }

  if (file != NULL)
    fclose(file);
  free(line);
}
```

lines are read correctly in this function when printf but output null in the batch_mode function

```
ssize_t read_line(char *line, FILE *file, char *cmd) {
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read = 0;

  read = getline(&line, &len, file);

  printf("%s\n", line);
  if (read == -1) {
    printf("Coudn't read line\n");
    return -1;
  }

  char *copy = line;
  cmd = strsep(&copy, " ");
  printf("%s\n", cmd);

  return 0;
}
```

and when trying this code it outputs that it can't read the file because it's executing more than once

```
void batch_mode(char *path) {
  char *line = NULL;
  ssize_t error = 0;
  char *cmd = NULL;
  FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Coudn't read file\n");
    return;
  }

  while ((error = read_line(line, file, cmd)) != -1) {

    int thread = fork();

    if (thread == 0) {
      char *myargs[] = {NULL};

      execv(cmd, myargs);
    } else {
      thread = wait(NULL);
    }
  }

  if (file != NULL)
    fclose(file);
  free(line);
}
```

Comment: Remember that function arguments in C are passed *by value* to functions. That means the value at the call-site is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Any change to this local argument variable will be lost when the function returns. That's wy the `getline` function need pointers to the variables, using the pointer-to operator `&`, so it will be able to modify the actual variables. This emulates *pass by reference*. And I say emulate, because C doesn't have that but C++ have. So please don't add the C++ tag for a C code question, because the solution might be different.

Comment: Your first step to solving this mystery is to figure out which language this code is written in: C or C++. You tagged your question as both C and C++ but they are two completely different languages. Is the shown code C or C++?

Comment: And in the future, test functionality in isolation. Like for example, create a very simple `main` function that calls the `read_line` function to make sure it works. You don't need to mix in everything else (like the `batch_mode` function).

Comment: sorry for the confusion i removed the c++ tag, i thought both communities could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has at least these problems:

**Never frees memory**

`read = getline(&line, &len, file);` allocates memory to `line`.  Code never frees it.

The calling code's `free(line);` is not the updated `line` of `read_line()`.

**Updating only local copy**

`cmd = strsep(&copy, " ");` does not update the calling code's `cmd`.

Calling code is doing `execv(NULL, myargs);`

---

Instead, pass the address of the pointer.  Perhaps

```
ssize_t read_line(char **line, FILE *file, char **cmd) {
```